# How to send canvas as a parameter to handler?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to draw a circles on the canvas cyclically with delays between every iteration. So, I realized it as a thread to use `Thread.sleep` method for delays.

Here is my `onDraw` method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (touching) {
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
            paint.setColor(_color);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {

                        while (f<=75){
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            drawHandler.sendMessage(drawHandler.obtainMessage());
                        }

                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Thread Interrupted");
                    }
                }
            });

            background.start();


        }
```

Here is my Handler:

```
private Handler drawHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, f, paint);
    }
};
```

This code cannot be compiled because canvas cannot be resolved in handler. How to send canvas object in handler? Generally, how it is possible to send parameters in handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either simply use the message.object to pass your canvas. 
But that's not the way drawing works.

Your handler should put your view in a given state and call invalidate, then in onDraw, check for that state and draw accordingly your circle. That would fit more gracefully in android drawing cycle.